# Advice on vector equation geometry

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I was wondering what a good approach and your technique for learning geometrically what objects are from their vector equations, often involving dot and cross products, are and 'easily' identifying them?

An example is $|x-a|=|x-b|$ is the perpendicular bisector but i only know this through learning loci formula rather than interpretation

Things like:
$x⋅u=|u|$ where $u$ would be a fixed vector, $x$ is a vector

any advice or good resources?

bump